# Hide real URL with ISAPI Rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Is it possible to hide real URL with HeliconTech's ISAPI Rewrite module? To be more specific, consider the following scenario:

1. User requests an URL "example.com/something".
2. "In the background", server redirects the request to another URL "anotherexample.com".
3. Contents from "anotherexample.com" are returned to the user (user still sees "example.com/something" in his/her browser address bar after response has been received).

So, the user must not be aware of the fact that contents came from different URL. If this isn't possible with ISAPI Rewrite, do there exist another ways to implement the functionality (in IIS 6 + SharePoint 2007 environment)?

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using proxy functionality in ISAPI_Rewrite 3. Here are the rules to put in .htaccess in the root of example.com site:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.anotherexample.com/$1 [P]
```